# plymouth test splash screen, allways shows Ubuntu with 4 dots

Tags: bash, plymouth

When I run following script and choose different splash screens I always receive a black screen with Ubuntu 16.04 and 4 dots. Plymouth works with the selected splash after reboot everything up and working so far.

Only testing in terminal does not how it should?

Please help, I want to be creative and customize my own splashes :-) thanks

```
!/bin/bash

echo "Choose the number of the theme you want to use, then [ENTER]"    
echo    
sudo update-alternatives --config default.plymouth    
sudo update-initramfs -u    
echo    

read -p "Do you want to test the theme? (Y/N) "    
if [ "$REPLY" != "n" -a "$REPLY" != "N" ] ; then    
 echo    
 echo "Running 10-second test..."    
 sudo plymouthd ; sudo plymouth --show-splash ; for ((I=0; I<10; I++)); do 
sleep 1 ; sudo plymouth --update=test$I ; done ; sudo plymouth --quit    
fi

exit
```